# I want to set a view controller as initial view controller

Tags: swift4

When user is already logged In then the app should be open from home page and he/she should not go to the login page again.

I have tried this code it shows no error but it is not working.

```
let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")  ?? ""
if !token.isEmpty
{
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let firstVC = 
                storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
                "initController") as! ViewController
   self.window?.rootViewController = firstVC
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }
```

I expect that when user is already logged In then when she again open the app he/she must directly go the home page and should not go again to the login page.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working". Do you go to another VC? Does it crashes?

Comment: It doesnot go to the another vc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""
if !token.isEmpty
 {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
                     "initController") as! HomeController
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = yourVC
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
```

Comment: Why `makeKeyAndVisible()` and `super.viewDidLoad()` here? Where you have put this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootVcIdentifier") as! UINavigationController

    self.view.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
```